# Classification and probability estimate using Naive Bayes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

Could you help me with classification problem using Naive Bayes, or give me some directions how to handle such problems.

The weather during summer was measured for six days as described in the table
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWvxT.jpg)

Using Naive Bayes with m-estimate and let m=2, estimate the probability:
A) That it will rain tomorrow, if it rains today, the temperature is low, there was no
storm, and the humidity is high.
B) That it rains today, if the humidity is low, there was a storm, and it is very cloudy.
C) That the temperature yesterday was high, if yesterday was a storm and it does not rain
today.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem. Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: it is not homework, it is one example I should be able to solve, and just don't know where to start, what probabilities to calculate first.